# Can I receive events from a BarcodeScanner in a background task?

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode-scanner, background-task, pointofservice

I am totally new to UWP and building an application that needs to take input from a barcode scanner using the UWP Point-of-Service API. I also have a legacy application that needs to take input from the scanner as key presses. My scanner (a Zebra 2208) doesn't seem to support switching between HID POS and HID keyboard mode automatically when it is claimed/unclaimed.

Is it possible to have my UWP app receive data from the scanner while running in the background and use the `InputInjector` API to send keys to the legacy application? If so, how?

Comment: See pdf ( https://www.visionid.ie/image/pdf/user-guides/ds2208.pdf) Interfaces on page 1-2.  Page 3-8 provided driver and sample software.  The scanner is USB (serial port) and can send/receive like any serial device.  The best way of communicating with device is using Asynchronous Send/Receive which will have events so your UWP will recognize incoming data.  the following msdn link shows how to use Async Read for Serial Port : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: The scanner fully supports HID POS mode, so there's no problem communicating with it from a UWP app. I just want to do so while my app is not in the foreground.

Comment: Bummer. I just found out about Extended Execution, though, so I'll try that and report back.

Answer (score 2):

@David Brown,

Background support for scanning barcodes was introduced in Windows 10 version 1903 (build 18362).  This capability was also added to 1809 (build 17763) with the servicing update released in April 2019 ([KB4490481](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4490481/windows-10-update-kb4490481)).  Please update your Windows installation to one of the above and give it a try.

Terry Warwick, Microsoft